# In bash how do I match the a string of the form [SOME_ALPHA_NUM_WORD]?

Tags: regex, bash

I have tried stuff like `=~ "\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\]"` which I would expect would work but doesnt. I also tried `"[[A-Za-z0-9]+]"` and `"\[[:alnum:]+\]"`. What am I doing wrong? Sample line I want to match: `[RTNUT18]` (I am iterating through a file, some lines are of this form)

This is my code snippet:

```
while read line;
do
    if [[ $line =~ "^\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\]$" ]]; then
        echo match
    else
        echo no match
    fi
done < $1
```

This is a sample file:

```
[RBPAT7]
Whatever=foo,bla
Otherline
RRR
```

and I run:

```
./script.sh thefile.txt
```

I am not getting a hit on the `[RBPAT7]` line at all

Comment: Why aren't you using grep for this?

Comment: Well in the actual script I am processing every line in an if elif elif elif...it's a config file of sorts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stuff like that isn't enough. You must use it in `[[`.

```
$ [[ [foo] =~ ^\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\]$ ]] ; echo $?
0
```

**EDIT:**

Unlike `test`, `[[` does not need quotes around its arguments. Your code matches nothing, since you can't have `"` before the beginning of the line, nor `"` after the end. Remove the quotes.